# BashOperator in Airflow for Spark submit Jinja Template Issue

Tags: airflow

I have a bash script spark_submit.sh that I want to use for scheduling my airflow job with a the BashOperator. The spark_submit.sh uses ivy to pull in the dependencies and then starts job.

spark_submit.sh looks like:

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.jars.ivySettings=.ivy2/ivysettings.xml" --repositories https://artifactory,https://artifactory/artifactory/maven-daco-releases --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0 --master yarn --name spark-job
SparkJob.py
```

When I run on server without Airflow the spark_submit.sh works fine but when use BashOperator in DAG the error I get is complete jibberish. Other BashOperator actions I have tried work fine so I am suspecting that the Jinja Templating is doing something to my spark_submit.sh which causes it to fail. Anybody encountered this before?
I know there is a SparkSubmitOperator but it is not installed on server yet.

Comment: can you provide some info about your airflow server? (airflow version, executor type)